# Arduino format integer into 4 bytes for send to I2C

Tags: arduino, i2c

I have 2 arduinos that communicate as master / slave using I2C. The slave one have to send to the master one a value that is changing like a rpm value.
This rpm value can be from 0 to 9999 rpm.
I want to send this value from slave to master as 4 bytes message

```
 Wire.write(rpm); // respond with message of 4 bytes
```

How can i make sure that rpm will be always 4 bytes?

Comment: `int` on an Arduino is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of chars to send a sequence of bytes. In Arduino int is 16 bit large. If you need to send always 4 bytes, a possible solution is to use masks to get the first 2 bytes and fill up the rest with zeros.

```
void SendInt(int value)
{
    char values[4];
    values[0] = value & 0xff;
    values[1] = (value & 0xff00) >> 8;
    values[2] = 0;
    values[3] = 0;

    Wire.write(values, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On this link you can check list of arduinos datatypes

https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/DatatypePractices

You may want to use long or unsigned long. Another way is to convert your rpm value to string and filling zeros when needed at left.

```
Wire.write(""+rpm);
```

Zero filling example:

```
String zeros = "";
if(rpm < 1000)
    zeros += "0";
if(rpm < 100)
    zeros += "0";
if(rpm < 10)
    zeros += "0";

Wire.write(zeros + rpm);
```

Comment: That's why there is the other example.